# What is the name of this plant and can it grow without sunlight?

Tags: identification, succulents

[image]

Hello Can anyone tell me what is the name of this plant ?

Comment: Looks like a Jade plant or at the very least a succulent along the same lines.  Any plant that is green HAS TO HAVE sunlight.  That is the entire reason for chlorophyll, the green stuff.  Those chlorophyll with light do photosynthesis.  Photosynthesis is the basic principle for plants to MAKE THEIR OWN FOOD.  Fertilizer is not food.  Light and photosynthesis makes food for the plant...as long as there are basic chemicals that the plant needs to do photosynthesis.  YES THIS PLANT NEEDS LIGHT.  Grins!!

Comment: Have you recently transplanted this plant?  Please be careful when watering.  Only water enough to wet the top 2" and not the entire pot of soil.  Their roots are shallow.  A better pot would have been half this height, clay is great.  Succulents hate too much water.  They store their own supply over and above their needs and they also have very shallow root systems.  Did you put rock or gravel beneath this soil?